# Delegation issue

Tags: domain-name-system, delegation

I have a small vps in the Netherlands and a domain registered with bluehost.

I added this domain account (WHM) to my vps by changing the nameserver of the correspondent domain on bluehost to ns1.xx.com and ns2.xx.com - Is that the correct way to achieve this or is there more involved? Everything seems to work fine using this method but I have just performed a test on pingdom with the following result:

```
    No name servers found at child.

    No name servers could be found at the child.
    This usually means that the child is not configured to answer queries about the zone.

    Superfluous name server listed at parent: ns1.xx.com

    A name server listed at the parent, but not at the child, was found.
    This is most likely an administrative error.
    You should update the parent to match the name servers at the child as soon as possible.

    Superfluous name server listed at parent: ns2.xx.com

    A name server listed at the parent, but not at the child, was found.
    This is most likely an administrative error.
    You should update the parent to match the name servers at the child as soon as possible.
```

Sorry I am a beginner but some advise would be highly appreciated, thank you very much,
Patrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pointing your domain's name servers at your VPS, but not running an actual DNS server on that VPS.

DNS works much like a phone book - it is a list of names like www.example.com and their corresponding IP address.  The name servers (ns1.xxx.com and ns2.xxx.com) tell your computer where to find the phone book that has all the information for your domain.

You could install a DNS server like BIND on your VPS and configure it.  But proper DNS requires you to have two seperate servers to run DNS from.  It can be done from a single system, but you are adding a huge point of failure.

Most hosting companies offer free or cheap DNS hosting.  They will likely have a simple control panel to set it up, and will tell you what name servers you need to use (likely something like ns1.bluehost.com, but check their documentation or contact their support).

Without an actual DNS server running somewhere, nobody will be able to lookup any records for your domain.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information Grant - very informative!